# Refreshing a specific div using jquery/ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, refresh

I have a table with orders and i'm trying to refresh the table every 5 seconds without refreshing the whole page.
After some research i found that i need to use this function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
});
function refreshTable(){
    $('#the_div_you_need_to_refresh').load('path', function(){
        setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });
}
```

The problem is that i dont' really understand what should i put in .load('path') beacuse if i write it like this,it will double my header and it will give me an error:

```
.load('<?php echo base_url('page name')?>',function(){
         <--function content-->
})
```

My view page is this:

```
<h2><?= $title;?></h2>
<div id="table_container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="orders_table">
        <thead>
        <--content-->
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($orders as $order):?>
            <tr class="active">
                <--content-->
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And my controller is this:

```
public function index(){

            if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                redirect('users/login');
            }
            $data['title'] = "Comenzi";
            $data['orders'] = $this->order_model->get_orders();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('orders/comenzi',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
```

Can you explain to me how should i do this,please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create new action in your controller. for example.

```
public function newData(){

    if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        redirect('users/login');
    }
    $data['title'] = "Comenzi";
    $data['orders'] = $this->order_model->get_orders();

    $this->load->view('path_to_your_table_view',$data);
}
```

in your script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $("#table_container").empty();
        $("#table_container").load("<?php echo base_url('newData')?>", function(){
            setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

i hope it will help.

Comment: That script will just erase my whole table and nothing more.
Maybe it was important to say that in <tbody> i have a foreach to loop in the products array

Comment: you need to create new view page that loop new row data and append it to the div

Comment: omg,i'm so bad... -.-
so "path_to_your_table_view" will be a new view,but how do i put the new data in the first table?
sorry for so many questions,but i don't really understand this

Answer (score 0):

This is an asynchronous request which is used to get data from some other resource. In order to load fresh data after every 5 sec you need to create a page/controller which would be hit by this load function.

you need to enter the url of this page/controller in the `path` variable.

That controller is supposed to return the fresh data which you would append or replace using the jquery

Comment: Hmm,ok
I will try to do this and i will come back with an update
Edit: In thtat controller i need to make a new request to the databse,right?